# Rename Gears of War Judgement to Gears of War Judgment

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can we change the tag [gears-of-war-judgement](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-of-war-judgement) to [gears-of-war-judgment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-of-war-judgment) and possibly create a synonym. This just fixes a common spelling mistake.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gears_of_War:_Judgment) the spelling of the current tag is incorrect.

Comment: Engish vs American is not a common spelling mistake :p

Comment: @Lyrion it's a proper title, therefore it's a spelling mistake.

Comment: @Lyrion I like how you misspelt "English" there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never. Done.

Answer (score 2):

All eight questions have been edited and are now tagged properly. Just need a mod to create the synonym now to prevent any future tag splitting.